# Console does not record mouse wheel events

Tags: c, windows

I am working on a TUI program with console on Windows 10. I would like to implement widgets that allow vertical scrolling when the user interacts with the mouse wheel. However the console does not record any of the mouse wheel events.

The [sample code below](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/Console-Docs/blob/master/docs/reading-input-buffer-events.md) from Microsoft does not record mouse wheel events even though my mouse wheel is working since windows manage to scroll the console content. All other mouse input events are working (click, move...).

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

HANDLE hStdin;
DWORD fdwSaveOldMode;

VOID ErrorExit(LPCSTR);
VOID KeyEventProc(KEY_EVENT_RECORD);    // the "case MOUSE_WHEELED:" in this function never happens
VOID MouseEventProc(MOUSE_EVENT_RECORD);
VOID ResizeEventProc(WINDOW_BUFFER_SIZE_RECORD);

int main(VOID)
{
    DWORD cNumRead, fdwMode, i;
    INPUT_RECORD irInBuf[128];
    int counter=0;

    // Get the standard input handle.

    hStdin = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    if (hStdin == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        ErrorExit("GetStdHandle");

    // Save the current input mode, to be restored on exit.

    if (! GetConsoleMode(hStdin, &fdwSaveOldMode) )
        ErrorExit("GetConsoleMode");

    // Enable the window and mouse input events.

    fdwMode = ENABLE_WINDOW_INPUT | ENABLE_MOUSE_INPUT;
    if (! SetConsoleMode(hStdin, fdwMode) )
        ErrorExit("SetConsoleMode");

    // Loop to read and handle the next 100 input events.

    while (counter++ <= 100)
    {
        // Wait for the events.

        if (! ReadConsoleInput(
                hStdin,      // input buffer handle
                irInBuf,     // buffer to read into
                128,         // size of read buffer
                &cNumRead) ) // number of records read
            ErrorExit("ReadConsoleInput");

        // Dispatch the events to the appropriate handler.

        for (i = 0; i < cNumRead; i++)
        {
            switch(irInBuf[i].EventType)
            {
                case KEY_EVENT: // keyboard input
                    KeyEventProc(irInBuf[i].Event.KeyEvent);
                    break;

                case MOUSE_EVENT: // mouse input
                    MouseEventProc(irInBuf[i].Event.MouseEvent);
                    break;

                case WINDOW_BUFFER_SIZE_EVENT: // scrn buf. resizing
                    ResizeEventProc( irInBuf[i].Event.WindowBufferSizeEvent );
                    break;

                case FOCUS_EVENT:  // disregard focus events

                case MENU_EVENT:   // disregard menu events
                    break;

                default:
                    ErrorExit("Unknown event type");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    // Restore input mode on exit.

    SetConsoleMode(hStdin, fdwSaveOldMode);

    return 0;
}

VOID ErrorExit (LPCSTR lpszMessage)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", lpszMessage);

    // Restore input mode on exit.

    SetConsoleMode(hStdin, fdwSaveOldMode);

    ExitProcess(0);
}

VOID KeyEventProc(KEY_EVENT_RECORD ker)
{
    printf("Key event: ");

    if(ker.bKeyDown)
        printf("key pressed\n");
    else printf("key released\n");
}

VOID MouseEventProc(MOUSE_EVENT_RECORD mer)
{
#ifndef MOUSE_HWHEELED
#define MOUSE_HWHEELED 0x0008
#endif
    printf("Mouse event: ");

    switch(mer.dwEventFlags)
    {
        case 0:

            if(mer.dwButtonState == FROM_LEFT_1ST_BUTTON_PRESSED)
            {
                printf("left button press \n");
            }
            else if(mer.dwButtonState == RIGHTMOST_BUTTON_PRESSED)
            {
                printf("right button press \n");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("button press\n");
            }
            break;
        case DOUBLE_CLICK:
            printf("double click\n");
            break;
        case MOUSE_HWHEELED:
            printf("horizontal mouse wheel\n");
            break;
        case MOUSE_MOVED:
            printf("mouse moved\n");
            break;
        case MOUSE_WHEELED:// this case never shows up when I use the wheel
            printf("vertical mouse wheel\n");
            break;
        default:
            printf("unknown\n");
            break;
    }
}

VOID ResizeEventProc(WINDOW_BUFFER_SIZE_RECORD wbsr)
{
    printf("Resize event\n");
    printf("Console screen buffer is %d columns by %d rows.\n", wbsr.dwSize.X, wbsr.dwSize.Y);
}
```

Comment: On windows 10 for most supported versions you should use VT mouse support and not the older win32 methods. They just exist for back compat now. [This is documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/mouse-event-record-str) on the very structure you're trying to read from. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences

Comment: [ncurses](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/intro.html) might provide the desired functionality.

Comment: Works fine as posted.  If the cursor looks like a block instead of an underline then you have QuickEdit enabled and won't get scroll events.  Alt+Space > Properties > untick QuickEdit.

Comment: QuickEdit mode is disabled.